# Proper PHP/MySQL syntax help needed

Tags: php, mysql, database, syntax, mysqli

I've been chasing a bug all day in my code. Here's the long and short of it:

I have a variable that is passed through a query string and I want to use that variable in my MySQLi query. A-like so:

```
$variable;

$info = dbConnect('query');
$eInfo = "SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE fieldname = '$variable%'";
$eiData = $info->query($eInfo) or die(mysqli_error());
$eInfo = $eiData->fetch_assoc();
```

The emphasis is the % after the variable name. I'm no PHP expert but I remember picking this trick up a while back and it has worked for me on all my DB-driven websites EXCEPT the new one I'm developing.

The above query returns no data from the table.

BUT...

if I omit the % as follows:

```
$variable;

$info = dbConnect('query');
$eInfo = "SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE fieldname = '$variable'";
$eiData = $info->query($eInfo) or die(mysqli_error());
$eInfo = $eiData->fetch_assoc();
```

The query executes and I get my data.

WHY after writing queries where I want to use a variable using the syntax '$variable%' would this no longer work? Just dropping the % ('$variable') makes it work A-OK, which has me utterly baffled.

For what it's worth, I run a dedicated server and suPHP was recently installed, if that has any remote chance of helping make sense here (PHP 5.2.17 is my current version).

Again, I'm no PHP whiz, but after checking code form older sites I have done with MySQLi queries, the % was always there when appending a variable into a query.

I'm completely dead in the water here. Any help you can provide would be so insanely appreciated that it defies explanation.

Comment: Are you thinking of text fields with a condition of `field LIKE 'value%'` instead of `field = 'value%'`? `%` is a wildcard with `LIKE`, but it's literal with `=`.

Comment: Also, if you're throwing that variable directly in the query like that, you're vulnerable to SQL injection. [Bind parameters](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) with a parameterized query instead. (See example at link.)

Comment: @Wiseguy - How do you db query without passing a variable directly?

Comment: @Wiseguy Um...no idea. All I know is that it has worked on every other site I have done that was DB-driven, but this one seems to be different. I checked out the link, but I've had a fit with the PHP manual as it seems to be written for people who already know this stuff. For those of us learning, it's dreadfully antiseptic. #stilllost

Comment: Odd. Simply throwing a `%` on the end of everything doesn't make sense to me. I'm only guessing that they all used `LIKE` instead of `=`, since I otherwise don't see how it would work at all. Long story short, from what I can tell, `%` shouldn't be there. If `$variable` is "wiseguy", the query shouldn't find results unless the stored value is literally "wiseguy%" with "%" on the end, which I doubt is the case.

Comment: @Wiseguy Ok, that makes a lot more sense. In the past I have done this with the % at the end of the variable with success (security issues aside...ugh, this is never-ending) but today, I once again became the person that only this happens to.

Comment: @Wiseguy PS - I don't use LIKE in my queries if that helps.

Comment: Ok, then based on what I'm understanding, I have no idea why all those other queries ever worked. :-p

Comment: @Wiseguy Well, that's a more honest answer than I've rec'd anywhere else. Usually everyone else chides us newbies for not knowing everything. Hell, we're at a loss as to how to even phrase questions when we know so little. Thanks for the touch of humor. I'm going to drive a claw hammer into my skull now.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put variables in a string where interpreting where the variable name ends is difficult, use `{$var}` like so:

```
$eInfo = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname LIKE '{$variable}%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%` is a wildcard for `LIKE` queries. So if you use `%` in a query with `WHERE var = 'cow%'`, it's going to search the database for the literal string `cow%`.

1. `cow`
2. `cows`
3. `cow%` (match)
4. `the cow`

In a Like query: `WHERE var LIKE 'cow%'` the following will match:

1. `cow` (match)
2. `cows` (match)
3. `cow%` (match)
4. `the cow`

See [MySQL Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html).